# How to pass an array as a parameter in a class constructor in PHP

Tags: php, constructor

I'm trying to pass these parameters in my class constructor:

1. `$tableName`: Database table name.
2. `$id`: ID field name of my database table.
3. `$tableFields`: Field names of my database table.

Parameter 1 and 2 always will be only 1, but parameter 3 is variable, maybe 2, maybe 4 or maybe 15.

So, I need to save it into an array, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Guys, can you help me to understand this?

```
<?php
    class GenerateCrud {
    
        // Properties.
        
            public $tableName;
            public $id;
            public $tableFields = array();
    
        // Constructor.
        
            function __construct($tableName, $id, $tableFields){
                $this->tableName = $tableName;
                $this->id = $id;
                $this->tableFields[] = $tableFields;
            }
    }
    
    $myObject = new GenerateCrud('users_test', 'id', 'field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4');
?>
```

Comment: `$myObject = new GenerateCrud('users_test', 'id', ['field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4']);`

Comment: And then `$this->tableFields = $tableFields;`

Comment: You could also do `function __construct($tableName, $id, ...$tableFields)` which will put any parameters beyond the second into an array.

Comment: Thank you guys. Finally I used @RiggsFolly method! Now it works!

Comment: Good. Do you understand **why** it worked?

Comment: I think yes, because is only syntaxys, I guess. I have to use this ```[]``` when I instance the object, this way I'm saying is an array. Also, in the constructor and in my properties, I have to especify ```[]```. Thank you!

Comment: Yes that's right, it makes it an array. just checking, because sometimes people just  happily copy solutions without knowing what it means, and then come back here the next day with the same type of mistake again! Happy coding.

Comment: Yeah! Im at work and I'm interested in learning and be better and better every day! Thank you, happy coding to you too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
$this->tableFields = $tableFields;
```

And:

```
$myObject = new GenerateCrud('users_test', 'id', ['field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4']);
```